# Equivalent Definition of the Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x$, that is:
$$\lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$
I want to there there exists $p$ continuous on an interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ such that $p(0)=0$ and:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+p(h)h$$
We could define $p(0)=0$ and $p(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x)$. How do I prove continuity of $p$?

Comment: I'm not sure, I feel like it could be any function that goes to $0$?

Comment: Ok I have edited to ask the thing that is confusing me.

Comment: Why are there absolute values on the definition of $p$?

Comment: Removed, thanks.

Comment: But $f$ differentiable at $x$ does not imply $f$ is continuous anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You just need $f$ to be continuous, and be differentiable at $x$. If $h \neq 0$, the $p$ is continuous at $h$ since $f$ is continuous. Cearly $p(h) \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ (because $f'(x)$ exists), then $p$ is also continuous at $0$

Comment: That makes sense, but this means these are not equivalent definitions, because one requires $f$ to be continuous around $x$.

Comment: That...was not your question. And I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ($p$ is continuous) if and only if ($f$ is continuous, and is differentiable at $x$)

Comment: I mean one definition is that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ is $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists. The other definition is that there exists $f',p$ such that $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+p(h)h$ for an interval around $x$ and $p$ continuous on that interval.

Comment: That was more clear

Comment: So we know that the usual definition of "differentiable" implies your definition, now we want to know if ir goes the other way around